# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules
import pandas as pd
import requests
import numpy as np

# Set ipython's max row display
pd.set_option('display.max_row', 1000)

# Insert your CrisisNET API key
api_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

# Insert your CrisisNET request API
api_url = 'http://api.crisis.net/item?sources=twitter&tags=weather'

# Create the request header
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key}

# Define how many data points you want
total = 10000

# Create a dataframe where the request data will go
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Define a function called get data,
def get_data(offset=0, limit=100, df=None):
    # create a variable called url, which has the request info,
    url = api_url + '&offset=' + str(offset) + '&limit=' + str(limit)
    # a variable called r, with the request data,
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # convert the request data into a dataframe,
    x = pd.DataFrame(r.json())



    # expand the dataframe
    x = x['data'].apply(pd.Series)
    # add the dataframe's rows to the main dataframe, df, we defined outside the function
    df = df.append(x, ignore_index=True)

    # then, if the total is larger than the request limit plus offset,
    if total > offset + limit:
        # run the function another time
        return get_data(offset + limit, limit, df)
    # but if not, end the function
    return df

# Run the function
df = get_data(df=df)

# Check the number of data points retrieved
len(df)

# Check for duplicate data points
df['id'].duplicated().value_counts()

# Drop all duplicate data points
df = df.dropna(how='all')

df.to_csv('TwitterWeather.csv')

# View the first 10 data points
print df.head()
```

and I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Somewhere, you have a `unicode` object that you're either trying to `decode` even though it's already decoded, or trying to use as if it were a `str` (e.g., adding it to a `str`, or passing it to a function that requires a `str`), in which case you need to `encode` it. Show us the whole traceback and it will tell you which expression is causing this, instead of making us guess.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback and a link to your data? It looks like you might want to "decode" your text, which is to say, you might want to convert it to unicode. To do so, though, you need to know the character encoding of the data you're working on. Do you know the character encoding (e.g. "utf-8")?

Comment: @Mona Jalal, I removed your  api key from your question

Answer (score 6):

As others suggested, you have a unicode string. Such a string returns error if you try to write it to a file. Looks like the error occurs when you save the dataFrame to a csv file.

To solve this problem, you will first need to convert the string to unicode. You could write a function such as:

```
def change_text(text):
    return text.encode('utf-8')  # assuming the encoding is UTF-8
```

You can then apply this to the column that has unicode characters as thus:

```
df['<column_name>'] = df.apply(change_text,axis=1)
```